# Telerik Upgrade in winforms

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik

i completed the project with Telerik Q3 2011. now i want to more upgrade the latest Telerik. Shall i import the latest Telerik DLL instead of old one? is it the way of Telerik upgrade or any other standard way to upgrade the Telerik for existing projects

```
Telerik 2011 Q3 - Telerik 2013 q3
```

Answer (score 3):

After the installation of the Telerik update Q3 2013, open your project in visual studio. In VS top menu bars, go to Telerik menu click on

> > "Radcontrols for Winforms" and then on the
> >
> > "Update Wizard" and follow the instructions.

Thats it. The new dll will be replaced automatically during the update process.

Comment: To add to this, also consider installing the Telerik Control Panel.  This app will alert you if any upgrades are available and downloads them for you.  Once downloaded, follow the steps above.